# Collect each service's display name and status

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I want to get list of services with their display name and their status.

This is what I have tried:

```
    for /f "tokens=2" %s in ('SC query state^= all ^| find "DISPLAY_NAME"') do @(for /f "tokens=4" %t in ('SC query %s ^| find "STATE"') do @echo %s is %t)
```

But this returns only limited services such as disk, etc.

Comment: if you are using this code in batch file you need to double the percentage sign

Comment: yeah i have used %% in a batch file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect task for the built-in WMI command line executable, `WMIC.exe`.

From the cmd.exe prompt:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %A In ('"WMIC Service Get DisplayName, Name, State"') Do @For /F "Delims=" %B In ("%A") Do @Echo(%B
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('"WMIC Service Get DisplayName, Name, State"'
) Do @For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do @Echo(%%B
@Pause
```

Comment: Thanks Compo..It works like a slice...just i need to add wmic in my environment variables and done...Thanks Com....

Answer (score 0):

Try getting help from powershell directly in your batch file, like this for example (save as .bat and run it). In the example i type it to the screen and give you ALL services, RUNNING ONLY, and STOPPED ONLY but you could do basically what you want with the content of that txt file (search it with a loop, save a part to a variable, etc.).

```
@echo off&cls

pushd %~dp0

echo.
echo List ALL services
pause
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "powershell Get-Service | Out-File services.txt"
type services.txt
echo.


echo List services that are RUNNING only
pause
find "Running" services.txt


echo.
echo List services that are STOPPED only
pause
find "Stopped" services.txt
pause


:cleanup
del /f services.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Raphael, but it is not able to identify powershell somewhere my mistake and in other system it works smooth!!!!!...Thanks

Comment: The solution above is better since it doesn't rely on powershell :) Glad i could provide an alternative though.